# Discount rates & Present value in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors, one with different interest rates in a monthly basis, and one with cashflows:

```
interest<-c(0,.0448,.0452,.0428,.0428,.0452,.051,.0475,.04997)
cash_flows<-c(44273.81  44176.68  66849.14 123792.30 101141.25 190894.12  82724.14 257075.63 176920.29 482068.00 429030.01 348291.50).
```

The first element of the interest vector is  0, because that is my present value basis. I want to take all values to that point; all the other values are interest rates of all the other months, I intend to discount them to that first period. The cash flows are also divided in a monthly basis. The R procedure that I am writing is the following:

```
discount_vector<-(1+i)^-(1:length(i)-1)
discount_vector*cash_flows
```

And in order to get the total amount investment I just call the following

```
sum(discount_vector*cash_flows).
```

Are my conceptual reasoning and code correct?

Tanks for any attention and support

Present value of formula using discount factor

```
i<-c(0,.0448,.0448,.0452,.0428,.0428,.0428,.0452,.0451,.0475,.0475,.04997)
cash_flows<-c(44273.81  44176.68  66849.14 123792.30 101141.25 190894.12  82724.14 257075.63 176920.29 482068.00 429030.01 348291.50).

discount_vector<-(1+i)^-(1:length(i)-1)
discount_vector*cash_flows
```

Comment: Hello azinsera. First of all, this place is for questions about programming languages, but your question (the code, except for the lack of colons in cash_flows, is ok) is mainly about  the conceptual reasonning of PV. That said, at first sigth it looks ok, but i  1: you do not need to set first i == 0, 2nd check if  it is ok that 44273.81 be positive.